# Remove points dir($path)

Tags: php, path

I am developing an application in which an administrator can upload files and you can read about users.

The problem I have when as shown, points `dir($path)` me appear;

Attached a picture with the problem:

[image: Remove points within the circle]

I want to remove the points!

As I can do that do not appear? I tried CSS and find some other way to develop but no way.

This is the code:

```
$path="../administrador/entrenos/"; 
$directorio=dir($path);
while ($archivo = $directorio->read())
    {
    $descarga = $path."".$archivo;
            echo "<a href=".$descarga.">".$archivo."</a><br>";

        }   
$directorio->close();
```

any ideas?

Comment: `if (substr($archivo, 0, 1) === '.') { continue; }` inside your while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
while ($archivo = $directorio->read())
    {
    if ($archivo == "." || $archivo == "..") {
       continue;
    }
    $descarga = $path."".$archivo;
            echo "<a href=".$descarga.">".$archivo."</a><br>";

        }
```

Comment: same answer and same time :)

Comment: Hahah, yeah!, I have answered a little earlier :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code to not display the dir with . and ..

```
while ($archivo = $directorio->read()){
    if($archivo === '.' || $archivo === '..') {continue;}
    $descarga = $path."".$archivo;
    echo "<a href=".$descarga.">".$archivo."</a><br>";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with [array_diff](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [scandir](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) can be implemented like below.

```
$path = "../administrador/entrenos/";
array_walk(array_diff(scandir($path), ['.', '..']), function ($archivo) use ($path) {
    $descarga = $path . $archivo;
    echo "<a href='{$descarga}'>{$archivo}</a><br>";
});
```